# distcc pump mode fails to compile with armv6-none-linux-androideabi

Tags: android, macos, cross-compiling, distcc

I'm on two OS X machines, and I'm trying to build an app for Android, using distcc pump mode.
I already got distcc to work on non-pump mode, and everything's fine.

I have two machines that are completely identical, with the same executables on both sides, on the same paths. For some reason, pump mode does not send any includes, and does all the preprocessing locally.

On the machine that starts the compilation, I get this:

```
__________Using distcc-pump from /usr/local/bin
__________Using       10 distcc servers in pump mode
WARNING include server: Preprocessing locally. Include server not covering: Could not locate name of translation unit: ['armv6-none-linux-androideabi', '<source_file>']. for translation unit 'unknown translation unit'
```

I searched around for clues, but the most predominant problem I could find was the include server timing out. So I changed the timeout from 3.8 to 30 seconds, recompiled it, installed it, and I still got this.

I tried another project, compiling some C++ code with pump distcc, for the local machine (not for Android), and it simply works.
What does this mean?